# How can I show hud on the right time with shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Background**

1. Navigation Controller View
2. Table with cells having ftp information
3. Cell segue will connect to ftp server and show lists
4. shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier will check if server's connection condition
5. if it's able to connect to the ftp server, it it will perform prepareForSegue

When a cell is clicked, I am showing HUD with "connecting..." and when it verifies, push to next page.

**Problem** : HUD doesn't show up right away and shows right before it's pushing to next view. Tried with various different HUD just in case, but fails. I am sure it's not the HUD.

**Question** : How can I start HUD right away upon click cell? Is shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier a right place to start show HUD? I tried with dispatch_async or sync but I have to return YES/NO to should perform segue or not.

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if([identifier isEqual:@"ConnectServer"])
    {
        self.HUD = self.prototypeHUD;
        self.HUD.textLabel.text = @"Connecting...";
        [self.HUD showInView:self.navigationController.view];
    NSManagedObject *obj = self.serverList[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        return [self checkServerConnection:obj];
    }
}
```

Comment: you can implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

Comment: @nburk, let me try and get back here. Thanks.

Comment: were you able to solve the issue? @handicop

Comment: @nburk no I haven't able to solve the issue yet. I will try your suggestion of "deleting segue from storyboard and trigger manually" later since I have to change other stuff as it's on navigation controller and deleting segue from storyboard won't show some stuff on xcode storyboard editor(eg toolbar with nav controller).

Comment: ok, let me know if you need some help :)

Comment: did it work for you by now? @handicop

Comment: i ended up with changing the process and now it's working. For the new process, I took your advice of trigger segue manually, and added dispatch_async to process login and then async to update ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` from the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. This method gets called right when the user taps on a cell. You will then have to perform a check whether this cell should trigger your hud (assumed you have different kinds of cells, otherwise you can omit the check).

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (<check if the appropriate cell was tapped>) {
       self.HUD = self.prototypeHUD;
       self.HUD.textLabel.text = @"Connecting...";
       [self.HUD showInView:self.navigationController.view];

   } 
}
```

Comment: when I add didSelectRowAtIndexPath and cell clicked, it flows shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier, prepareforsegue, and then didselectrow. Is it possible to change the method execution order?

Comment: hmm I don't think so unfortunately... these methods are alle invoked automatically by iOS, so you won't be able to change this flow. also it would't make sense to call `shouldPerformSequeWithIdentifier` **after** `prepareForSegue`. I answered a related question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946566/calling-performseguewithidentifier-doesnt-call-shouldperformseguewithidentifier/26946596#26946596

Comment: however, what you can do is **delete the segue from storyboard** and **trigger it manually**, or even don't use a segue and rather instantiate the destination view controller yourself (`[self.storyboard instantiateViewController...]``) and use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController]`